# How to add directory outside git repository location into project?

Tags: git, repository

I create a git repository for my project, and my project also uses few files outside of my repository location

The structure is something like this: This is my repository location.

```
C:\Users\userName\Desktop\GitProject\testProject
```

Other files are in this path:

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\otherFiles
```

My question would be: Can I add other directory, which is outside of my repository, into my repository? Or can one repository only has one root?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one root directory. In your case, I would suggest that you create a second git repository for the `otherFiles` that are stored `AppData`. You can then work with [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to commit things to the `otherFiles` repository, when you commit in the main repository.

Please don't create one big git repo in the first root that both have in common. Even if you cancel out (or ignore) all the subdirectories using `.gitignore`. This will be a pain for other people to check out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any file into your repository so that Git can track all of them. But if the other files must be under `C:\Users\userName\AppData\otherFiles` when you are building or running the project, you need to copy them to where they should be beforehand. The "copy" job can be done by manual or in a Makefile or a script.